# wrap of functions avoid duplicating

Tags: c++, c, wrapper

I have third party C library. I want to use it in c++
Every function return error code.
when i have to use it I have to write code like this:

```
int err;
err=libFun1(....);
check(err);
err=libFun2(....);
check(err);
```

I want to wrap this functions and avoid code duplication of check. Every of this librabry function have different number parameters. What will be a good design for this?

Comment: How about using exceptions?

Comment: While c++ does, c doesn't have exceptions.

Comment: You should pick one language, or specify which language you want answers in.

Comment: Is the `check` the same for all your functions?

Comment: @juanchopanza: It is perfectly ok to ask for a solution, that works in either ;)

Comment: @BodoThiesen Not really, but in any case that should be made clear in the question.

Comment: If you are either a C or a C++ evangelist, it may be not ok for you to share code between the two. For everyone else, especially those asking for ways to prevent code duplication, it is. EOD.

Comment: @BodoThiesen If the requirement was made clearly that the subset of C that is compatible with C++ is required, then it should be stated. Asking for answers in two or more languages is not good.

Comment: Looks like OP has long-since answered the question of what language they're writing in: C++. The C tagging is questionable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/edit 4: The C++11-Way using variadic templates, inspired by Gill Bates' solution:

```
template <typename T, class ...A> int CallWrapper(T func, A... args) {
    int error = func(args...);
    check(error);
    return error;
}

CallWrapper(libFun1);
CallWrapper(libFun2, 4711);
CallWrapper(libFun3, 42, 23);
```

/edit 5: older solutions, beginning with first solution:

```
#define LIBFUN1() do { \
    int err = libFun1(); \
    check(err); \
} while (0)

#define LIBFUN2() do { \
    int err = libFun2(); \
    check(err); \
} while (0)

LIBFUN1();
LIBFUN2();
```

Put the `#define`s in some header file. Please note the MISSING semicolon after the `while ()`. This way, you can naively use `LIBFUN1()` and so on in any context, where a statement is allowed like `if (...) LIBFUN1(); else LIBFUN2();`

/edit 3: Instead of using `#define`s, static inline functions would do the job too:

```
static inline int checked_libFun1() {
    int err = libFun1();
    check(err);
    return err;
}

static inline int checked_libFun2() {
    int err = libFun2();
    check(err);
    return err;
}

checked_libFun1();
checked_libFun2();
```

/edit 2: @Myst suggested to use variadic macros that contain the name of the function to call. This could look like this:

```
#define call_void(name) do { \
    int err = name(); \
    check(err); \
} while (0)

#define call_args(name, ...) do { \
    int err = name(__VA_ARGS__); \
    check(err); \
} while (0)

call_void(libFun1);
call_args(libFun2, 42);
```

The two macros are needed because you have to distinguish between functions not accepting any arguments and functions accepting any number of arguments greater one. So, here, `libFun2(42)` would be called

Comment: Such macros are not the C++ way of doing things.

Comment: But they are the C way of doing it and the C++ way doesn't work for C. Please note the presence of the C tag in the question.

Comment: You could probably use variable macros to both state the function's name and it's arguments....

Comment: The first one is close to C Style. Solution 4 definatly help. Plus one

Comment: what about solution 4?

Comment: my mistake solution 4

Comment: so, is there still a problem with that solution? If yes, let us know.

Comment: I approved your answer for solution 4 it's c++ style. And  solution 2 gives Idea for VAR_ARG even if it is not first choice for c++. VAR ARG still exists.

Answer (score 7):

How about a templated function:

```
template <typename T>
int CallWrapper(T func)
{
  int error = func();
  check(error);
  return error;
}
```

Then call it with `CallWrapper(libFun1);`.

Comment: I  think this is good but I sometimes have to pass parameters. I forget to show this in the question. Plus one, this is very near to what I need.

Comment: @VladimirYanakiev [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) may help you with the parameters.

Comment: Also take a look at [parameter packs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack)

Comment: my answer contains a variadic template solution at the bottom now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use exceptions and catch them.

One way is to use Macros like:

```
#include <exception>

#define THROW_ON_ERROR(libFunc) do{ \
    int err = libFunc(); \
    if(check(err)) \
        throw std::exception(); \
    }while(0); \
```

and you code will look like this:

```
try
{   
    THROW_ON_ERROR(libFun1);
    THROW_ON_ERROR(libFun2);
}catch(const std::exception& e)
{
//handle...
}
```

This method is not very modern but does the job. It was just to pass the point of converting the error status code convention which is the common way in C to exception handling which is a nice way in C++ (not sure if common).
Also you can use your own exceptions to pass some data.
You can do the same thing by calling a function like:

```
#include <functional>

class LibFuncException : public std::exception
{
public:
    explicit LibFuncException(int err) : m_err(err) {}
    int GetError() const { return m_err; }
private:
    int m_err;
};

void ThrowOnError(std::function<int()> libFunc)
{
    int err = libFunc();
    if(check(err)
        throw LibFuncException(err);
}
```

and your code can:

```
try{
    ThrowOnError(libFunc1);
    ThrowOnError(libFunc2);
} catch(const LibFuncException& e)
{
    std::cout << "Error: << e.GetError() << std::endl;
}
```

EDIT:

if your library function sometime receive arguments you can either call the `ThrowOnError` with a lambda like so:

```
int x = 10;
const char* str = "Hello World";
ThrowOnError([x, str]() { return libFuncWithArgs(x, str); });
```

Or if you want to be extreme you can have a variadic template like someone suggested already

Comment: I sometimes have to pass parameters. I forget to show this in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few ways to do this:

1. Template functions (@GillBates has you covered).
2. An inline function (maybe with variadic arguments).
3. Simple macros (@usr and @ZivS have you covered).
4. A variadic Macro.

Since you're writing for C++, I'd probably use Template functions... <strike>the only thing negative about that option is that function argument handling (assuming the library functions accept arguments) could be a headache.</strike>

I think the C approach of a variadic Macro would work better, also providing compile-time unwrapping (vs. runtime unwrapping).

i.e. (this is only an example, I didn't even test the code)

```
int checkerr(int err) {
   if(!err)
      return 0;
   // ... handle errors, exit if need be.
}

#define CALL_CLIB(fn_name, ...) checkerr((fn_name)(__VA_ARGS__))
```

You can use it like so:

```
 // will print "this is only 1 example"
 CALL_CLIB(printf, "this is only %d, %s", 1, "example");
```

You can make it also more complex, if you want, adding `try`, `catch` or whatever you want into the mix.

Comment: You can use variadic templates to accept arbitrary arguments.

Comment: Yes, he can. But why should he, if his solution works without? Just because you like C++ more than C?

Comment: Thank you, @juanchopanza . I'm not sure, since I'm more C oriented, but I think you'd run into a headache when the time comes to forward the argument to the wrapped function. I suspect the Macro approach might be easier... but I may be wrong.

Comment: @Myst No, it would be trivial. `std::forward` and all that.

Comment: @juanchopanza  - I'm happy it's trivial. Still, I have an affinity with C and the single line Macro. I probably wouldn't know how to write an example using `std::forward`. Part of the beauty, I guess, is the many approaches.

Comment: @Myst And who knows, the question might be C anyway, OP hasn't clarified that yet.

Comment: @juanchopanza  that's true :-D ... as a side note, a Macro moves the logic from a runtime wrapper to a compile-time wrapper... it's usually meaningless, but not always.

Comment: Actually, in the meantime, I saw, he DID: Library is 3rd party C, he codes in C++. So C++-only answers are valid.

Comment: @BodoThiesen  ... well, I guess my approach goes down the drain... 

Answer (score 0):

From given code, you may simply write

```
check(libFun1(/*...*/));
check(libFun2(/*...*/));
```

Possibly, you may want to wrap each method to have only one call from user side:

```
void chekedLibFun1(/*...*/) { check(libFun1(/*...*/)); }
void chekedLibFun2(/*...*/) { check(libFun2(/*...*/)); }
```

and so previous code becomes:

```
checkedLibFun1(/*...*/);
checkedLibFun2(/*...*/);
```